# Need help in understanding malloc(0) for my example

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to understand inners of double pointer (which is pointer holding another pointer) to form an array of pointers. So, I am trying to run the following code by experimenting on malloc to debugging and see how it works. I am unable to understand what `malloc(0)` does in my case, but my code works by outputting "Hello World".

What is the diff between

```
pToCharsPointers = (char**) malloc(0);
```

and

```
pToCharsPointers = (char**) malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
```

Please someone clarify what it is doing in my case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char **pToCharsPointers;

int main(void)
{
    pToCharsPointers = (char**) malloc(0);

    char* pToChars = "Hello";
    *pToCharsPointers = pToChars;

    *(pToCharsPointers + 1)= "World";

    printf("%s %s\n", *(pToCharsPointers + 0), *(pToCharsPointers + 1));

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I would really appreciate if you anyone could explain how double pointers works with an example in memory for visualizing as I fail to see myself even though I tried to read about this in many places.

EDIT: Thanks everyone for sharing your answers, and it really helped to understand. I got a valid pointer with malloc(0) when I printed it, and can dereference it also without issues during multiple tries. Wanted to understand why its working. Seems like in my case undefined behavior was actually a expected one.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `*pToCharsPointers` is equal to `pToCharsPointers[0]`, and `*(pToCharsPointers + 1)` is equal to `pToCharsPointers[1]`.

Answer (score 6):

In your code

```
(char**) malloc(0);
```

is wrong for two reasons, like

- Passing size as 0 is implementation defined behaviour and the returned pointer cannot be dereferenced. Quoting the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc),

  > If size is `0`, then `malloc()` returns either `NULL`, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to `free()`.
- [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Any code, attempting to use the returned pointer for a code like yours, will be essentially dereferencing invalid memory which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So, the output/behaviour of your program can neither be predicted nor reasonified.

OTOH, a statement like

```
pToCharsPointers = malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
```

is valid but you ought to check the validity of the returned pointer to ensure `malloc()` is success.

Comment: But my code works as expected which is why I asked this question. Can you tell me why please ?

Comment: @DineshG ***Seemingly*** working okay is one of the possibilities of undefined behavior.

Comment: @DineshG Probably because your implementation doesn't return  `NULL`, but some other value. You could print it. But all of **doesn't matter**, it's undefined behavior anyway.

Comment: Just to avoid any possible confusion, what @unwind meant is, _printing_ the returned pointer is OK, _dereferencing_ that is not.

Comment: Dear @**downvoter**, if you care to leave a comment along with the downvote it'll help me understanding the mistake and improve the post for better. Thank you.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The reason is your usual claim, that casting the return value is *wrong*.

Comment: @Ctx Thanks, much appreciated. Sorry, but I stand by my statement. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh No need to be sorry, freedom of speech is very precious ;)

Answer (score 3):

I will try to explain:

```
pToCharsPointers = (char**) malloc(0);
```

this line will bring to pToCharPointers a pointer that you **can't** use

but you can't know if an error will come. don't do that!

```
char* pToChars = "Hello";
*pToCharsPointers = pToChars;
```

this line will bring *pToCharsPointers to pToChar that pointing to the "Hello".

```
*(pToCharsPointers + 1)= "World";
```

this line will write in *(pToCharsPointers + 1), that you can't know to where it is pointing, "World". also, an option to an error but not for sure.

```
printf("%s %s\n", *(pToCharsPointers + 0), *(pToCharsPointers + 1));
```

this line will print "Hello Wolrd" if you didn't get any errors yet.

Answer (score 2):

It simply asks to allocate *zero* bytes. It is up to the implementation of [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) if it should return a null pointer or not.

Even if it returns a non-null pointer, you can't dereference it since it will automatically be out of bounds. Dereferencing the returned pointer will lead to *undefined behavior* in both cases.

When you do `malloc(2 * sizeof(char*))` you allocate enough space for two pointers to `char`.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`. Calling `malloc()` without a proper definition has undefined behavior. Explicitly casting its return value hides the fact that the compiler may assume it returns an `int` value. This cast is necessary in C++, where calling a function without a prior definition is invalid, but it is counter-productive in C.

Regarding your question: allocating a block of size zero can have two possible outcomes, depending on the implementation of your C library:

- `malloc(0)` can return `NULL`, and attempting to store values at this address has undefined behavior.
- `malloc(0)` can return a valid non-null pointer, but this pointer cannot be dereferenced, nor used to store anything as the size of the object it points to is `0`.

In both cases, your code has undefined behavior, which may or may not be a crash.